# How to get value from list in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

I am trying to extract value from a list but not able to get it. Can someone please help me how to do this?

Example:

```
[Row(col9=u'recordtype&>>/app/Janseen_CarePath/logs/log_file_master_job_load20200513_034027.log')]
```

Expected Result:

```
recordtype
```

Comment: Is that your list? is it a one piece of string in there? and is your string always structured that way? i.e. will it always have 'Row(col19=u' before your desired substring?

Comment: @Mit It is coming like that only sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IICU

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'Text':["[Row(col9=u'recordtype&>>/app/Janseen_CarePath/logs/log_file_master_job_load20200513_034027.log')]"]}

df1['word']=df1.text.str.extract('([a-z]+(?=[\&\>\>]))')
```

[image]